# JSON Array combine items based on an same ID

Tags: javascript

So I have these items and it has some duplicated ID's but the values are different. It might be more items but currently I used these items for example. The array result is like this:

```
"items": [
    {
        "id": "E46",
        "size": "5 Ounce"
    },
    {
        "id": "E46",
        "color": "Green"
    },
    {
        "id": "E32",
        "size": "8 Ounce"
    },
    {
        "id": "E32",
        "color": "Green"
    },
    {
        "id": "E4G",
        "size": "5 Ounce"
    },
    {
        "id": "E4G",
        "color": "Pink"
    },
    {
        "id": "E3C",
        "size": "8 Ounce"
    },
    {
        "id": "E3C",
        "color": "Pink"
    }
]
```

I'd like combine these and make it look like this:

```
"items": [
    {
        "id": "E46",
        "size": "5 Ounce"
        "color": "Green"
    },
    {
        "id": "E32",
        "size": "8 Ounce"
        "color": "Green"
    },
    {
        "id": "E4G",
        "size": "5 Ounce"
        "color": "Pink"
    },
    {
        "id": "E3C",
        "size": "8 Ounce"
        "color": "Pink"
    }
]
```

If it's possible, Thanks:

Comment: @bdkopen It has JavaScript tagged, but JSON in the title. Just guessing here, it's JSON that's created in JavaScript. Maybe partial code, maybe OP is just bad at JSON/JS. Who knows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var data = { items: 
[{ id: 'E46', size: '5 Ounce' },
 { id: 'E46', color: 'Green' },
 { id: 'E32', size: '8 Ounce' },
 { id: 'E32', color: 'Green' },
 { id: 'E4G', size: '5 Ounce' },
 { id: 'E4G', color: 'Pink' },
 { id: 'E3C', size: '8 Ounce' },
 { id: 'E3C', color: 'Pink' } ] }

var result = {}

data.items.forEach(function (item) { //1
    Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) { //2
        if (!result[item.id]) result[item.id] = {}; //3
        result[item.id][key] = item[key]; //4
    });
})
```

Here is what is happening:

**//1** We loop through each item in the `items` array

**//2** We loop through each `key` in individual `item` from the `items` array

**//3** We create a key-value pairing using the `item` id and an empty object

**//4** We add the current key-value pair our new `item` object made **inside** our `result` object.

The `result` object would then have this value:

```
{ E46: { id: 'E46', size: '5 Ounce', color: 'Green' },
  E32: { id: 'E32', size: '8 Ounce', color: 'Green' },
  E4G: { id: 'E4G', size: '5 Ounce', color: 'Pink' },
  E3C: { id: 'E3C', size: '8 Ounce', color: 'Pink' } }
```

If you wanted to put this back into an array, all you would have to do is loop through each key-value pair in the object and add all of the values to an array, like so:

```
var arrayResult = []
Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key) {
    arrayResult.push(result[key])
});
```

And then your `arrayResult` variable would have this value:

```
[ { id: 'E46', size: '5 Ounce', color: 'Green' },
  { id: 'E32', size: '8 Ounce', color: 'Green' },
  { id: 'E4G', size: '5 Ounce', color: 'Pink' },
  { id: 'E3C', size: '8 Ounce', color: 'Pink' } ]
```

which you could use anywhere else in your program.

Answer (score 1):

```
function mergeObjectWithSameId(items) {
  let output = []
  items.forEach((item) => {
    if (output.filter(existingItem => existingItem.id === item.id).length === 0) {
      output.push(item)
    } 
    else {
      const existingItem = output.filter(existingItem => existingItem.id === item.id)[0]
      Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
        if(!existingItem[key]) {
          existingItem[key] = item[key]
        }
      })
    }
  })
  return output
}
```

I have tested it in the Chrome console.

Just run `mergeObjectWithSameId(items)` and Voila you get your expecting result!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've looking for a JavaScript solution, and that you've already parsed the 'items' JSON in the question into a JavaScript Object (`itemsParsed` below), you can achieve the restructuring of your data in two steps.

The first is to create a hashmap of the data where the repeated 'id' property represents the keys in a new Object, like so...

```
var itemsParsed = theParsedJSON;

var itemHolder = (function() {
    var O = {}, ID;
    itemsParsed.forEach(function(o) {
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function(a) {
            if (a === 'id') {
                ID = o.id;
                if (!O[ID]) O[ID] = {};
            } else {
                O[ID][a] = o[a];
            }
        });
    });
    return O;
}());
```

This will return the Object `itemHolder` as so...

```
itemHolder = {
    E46: { 
        size: "5 Ounce" 
        color: "Green" 
    } 
    E32: { 
        size: "8 Ounce" 
        color: "Green" 
    } 
    E4G: { 
        size: "5 Ounce" 
        color: "Pink" 
    } 
    E3C: { 
        size: "8 Ounce" 
        color: "Pink" 
    }
};
```

The next step is to use this structure in another another step transformation from which fresh Objects can be created and pushed into new a array, like so...

```
var newItems = [];

Object.keys(itemHolder).forEach(function(n) {
    var tmp = itemHolder[n];
    var newObj = {
        id: n
    };
    Object.keys(tmp).forEach(function(x) {
        newObj[x] = tmp[x];
    });
    newItems.push(newObj);
});
```

The structure of the `newItems` array can be seen when the JSON.stringify method is applied to it...

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(newItems, null, 4));
/* ==>
[
    {
        "id": "E46",
        "size": "5 Ounce",
        "color": "Green"
    },
    {
        "id": "E32",
        "size": "8 Ounce",
        "color": "Green"
    },
    {
        "id": "E4G",
        "size": "5 Ounce",
        "color": "Pink"
    },
    {
        "id": "E3C",
        "size": "8 Ounce",
        "color": "Pink"
    }
]
*/
```

Hope that helps.  :)

- MDN: `Object.keys()` -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys
- MDN: `Array.forEach()` -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 0):

You could [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array. Create an accumulator object with each unique `id` as key and merge each object using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill) based on the `id`

```js
const items=[{id:"E46",size:"5 Ounce"},{id:"E46",color:"Green"},{id:"E32",size:"8 Ounce"},{id:"E32",color:"Green"},{id:"E4G",size:"5 Ounce"},{id:"E4G",color:"Pink"},{id:"E3C",size:"8 Ounce"},{id:"E3C",color:"Pink"}];

const merged = items.reduce((acc, o) => {
  acc[o.id] = Object.assign(acc[o.id] || {}, o)
  return acc;
}, {})

const output = Object.values(merged)

console.log(output)
```